# Is it possible to dump an Objects Properties and Methods?

Tags: python

Due to the lack of a class diagramm I need to explore the data structures by dumping objects to see what is in there.

How can I dump the Objects internals to the console?

In this snippet I tried to print the objects but I only get error messages 'TypeError'

```
def assignPose( plIdx ):
    rig = bpy.data.objects.get("rig")

    if rig != None:
        print("rig=" + str(tuple( rig ))) # TypeError: 'Object' object is not iterable
        print( "" + rig.__str__ )         # TypeError: Can't convert 'method-wrapper' object to str implicitly
        pl = rig.pose_library
        pl.poselib_apply_pose( plIdx )
    else:
        print("couldn't find rig.")
```

Comment: What do you want to see as output exactly? If you want bones of the rig try `tuple(rig.data.bones)`. If you want to get names of properties of rig itself, try `dir(rig)`

Comment: Pure Python questions like this are better placed over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). As you've found, there are many pre-existing ones there too, here's another: [How do I look inside a Python object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006169/)

Comment: @Aldrik I had to try several approaches since not all of them work with blenders data structures, so I posted the answer to document this for later reference.

Comment: @stacker Python has built-in functions to do what your after, see link in previous comment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I found a solution to get started:

```
def dump(obj):
   for attr in dir(obj):
       if hasattr( obj, attr ):
           print( "obj.%s = %s" % (attr, getattr(obj, attr)))
```

This is based on one of the methods suggested on this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192109/is-there-a-function-in-python-to-print-all-the-current-properties-and-values-of/192184#192184) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610883/how-to-know-if-an-object-has-an-attribute-in-python)

Instead of invoking `print` call `dump( anyobject )`

This would print something like:

```
...
obj.copy = <bpy_func Object.copy()>
obj.cycles_visibility = <bpy_struct, CyclesVisibilitySettings("")>
obj.data = <bpy_struct, Armature("rig")>
obj.delta_location = <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
obj.delta_rotation_euler = <Euler (x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0000), order='XYZ'>
obj.delta_rotation_quaternion = <Quaternion (w=1.0000, x=0.0000, y=0.0000, z=0.0
000)>
obj.delta_scale = <Vector (1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000)>
obj.dimensions = <Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)>
obj.draw_bounds_type = BOX
obj.draw_type = WIRE
obj.dupli_faces_scale = 1.0
...
```

Comment: Please add a reference (http://stackoverflow.com/a/192184/155813 ?) from where you found the solution, so that others can explore  related solutions/comments.

Comment: @mg007 Good idea, added a reference btw. this was the only one working with blenders objects.

Comment: I've built off this idea and extended it to do some recursion / memo-ization: [blender_dumpy.py](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/blender_server/blob/175054b15df1dc0b99795cc15fe80ef555d7dafa/blender_dump.py) - example snippet from the Race Spaceship demo: [gist snippet](https://gist.github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/296d04225763e017ce022782ca6ab63e)

Answer (score 3):

There is already an addon called *API Navigator* to explore the API.
It has to be enabeld first in the *User Preferences*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looked for this in 2.80, but guessing it may not be maintained :( See above comment for my hacky workaround based on object enumeration.