# Blender 2.80_Is there a way to make Blender File Browser remember its settings?

Tags: file-browser

I'm hoping there's a simple solution I'm overlooking to tell Blender 2.80 to remember its File Browser settings (ex. display size, sort by date modified, etc.) Has this situation been remedied in Blender 2.80?

I know about these ideas:
[How to make the file manager default to sorting by modification date?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23159/how-to-make-the-file-manager-default-to-sorting-by-modification-date)

Those potential solutions do not seem usable for me at this time due to my lack of knowing how to implement them. Also I think the addon referred to there gives an error at Blender preferences> addons> install addon, something like "addon needs upgrade to 2.80". Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

As of [April 14 2019 commit](https://developer.blender.org/rB6efac431a35c9792021eeb85b4eb0df04f88da80)  Blender 2.80 builds should have builtin ability to remember last used file browser display options globally per file type, as stated in [D4479](https://developer.blender.org/D4479).

Comment: Interesting, looks like they are trying to get Blender to remember File Browser settings. Here the little hourglass icon (sort by date modified) is reset every time I come back to the Blender File Browser ie when I open a Blender file, or when I save a Blender file. My hope is that Blender would simply remember to keep that hourglass enabled if I enable it,  rather than me having to click on it each time I save as, or open a file. Thanks for any other ideas.